# All employee's given raise at the same time my position changed

Tags: salary, work-environment

I work in a warehouse, and in this warehouse different positions get paid differently (obviously) - but something happened to me that I'm really confused about.

So, when I started with this company (a refurbishing company) I started through a temp service (everyone starts through temp and gets hired on after some months) as a product tester for pay rate ***x***.
So, fast forward to the point where I am hired on. A few weeks later, I am pulled into the office to discuss being moved departments (to become a computer technician, for pay rate ***y*** which is higher than ***x***). It was discussed my new pay would start after 60 days into the position (The wait was supposedly a waiting period for me to decide if I wanted to stay in the position). Anyways, during this 60 days (Maybe halfway through or so) everyone in the warehouse was gathered and told we would all be receiving wage increases (The wage increase for me would have been ***y***+$1.)

However, now several months later, I still have not received this pay raise because I technically did receive a pay raise after the talk of the warehouse raises. The management held off my signing of paperwork until right after the discussions on the wage changes.

All of the temp workers that are starting in the same position are making the new wage ***y*** before even being hired on.

Should I try to fight for this $1? I know most of it will be taken with taxes anyways, but I'm having a pretty hard time affording things.

Comment: Unless you are union or it is below minimum wage they get to set the pay.

Comment: @Frisbee Yes, I understand that, and that wasn't one of my questions.

Comment: Questions 2 and 3 are off topic here.  1 is a great question though

Comment: Question 3 "I'm pretty sure what they are doing is legal, but I wanted to be sure?"  That was edited out later by another person.

Comment: @Frisbee Yes, but I was more referring to the legal aspect of a verbal contract of getting a raise and then not following through. I understand they set the wages, but they can't just go around telling people they are getting raises and then not following through, legally, right?

Comment: Most of it will be taken in taxes? Don't forget, salaries tend to compound over the years because most raises are a percentage of current pay.

Comment: And at most 40% would go to taxes.  Chances are that is what will go with 25% being FICA but the other 15 being withholding.  Wanting that $1 is not unreasonable.  The question as you asked is "Is it worth fighting for it?"

Comment: This site is not for legal and I am not an attorney.  "Everyone in the warehouse was gathered and told we would all be receiving wage increases" is probably not legally binding nor enforceable.  Even if it was enforceable your situation would be vague at best.

Comment: @Frisbee - If you have a good attorney, it probably is enforceable.  That attorney is probably going to rack up 100k+ in fees and costs for something that is not a sure thing... but the costs and fees are a sure thing.

Comment: @Chad I don't have a question on the matter

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I've talked to all of my supervisors except the building manager so far, and I just keep hearing that I'll hear back from them soon.  But it's been months.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I try to fight for this $1?

Are your prepared to leave if they deny the raise?  Because chances are they are just going to say no to your first request.  If you are not willing to leave then all you are going to do it create conflict between you and your manager which is not going to help you with future raises/evaluations.

Can you afford to be demoted back to your Product Tester role and pay?  This could be a real possibility.  I have worked for several companies like this where the promise of higher pay with plentiful but actual raise were late or non-existent, and anyone who tried to rock the boat was demoted or fired.  I would not be surprised to find that many of your coworkers are also still waiting for their "across the board" raise.

It is even possible that what they have done is not legal and you could be entitled to back pay.  But chances are that is not the case, and unless you can afford the attorneys fees, and costs associated with a protracted legal battle over what will probably be far less than the costs, it is probably not worth the hassle.

You might consider talking with some of your peers, especially ones that have been with the company for some time, and finding out if this is their typical MO.  If it is you might want to consider forming a Union to protect your collective rights.  However never do any of this at work or on the clock.  Meet up after work for a drink or dinner and discuss it.  If there is support then find a national union and use their guidance on how to proceed.  *I am not saying you should Unionize, I am saying it is a potential solution if your employer is notorious for using these shady business practices*